# Performance Testing of AJAX calls via JMeter without WebDriver

Tags: jmeter

I have implemented one web application. In this application we have a start page.
In this start page, we have a search functionality which is a ajax call to render specific components.
For this page i have to perform load test. I tried with Recording Logic Controller to record the actions in the browser. When I run the recorded scripts, search function is not working.
I am not sure whether this approach is correct or not to perform load test for Ajax calls.

Could anybody let me know, how to perform load test for Ajax calls via JMeter!

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is not a browser so it neither renders response nor executes JavaScript. However it is capable of capturing AJAX request and it's up to you how to replay them.

There are multiple reasons of possible request failure: like missing or hard-coded parameter, missing header, etc, you can add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your test plan so see your search request and response details. The only way to sort this out is capturing the same scenario originated from JMeter and from real browser using sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), compare requests and configure JMeter accordingly.

See [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) for some approaches of load testing AJAX applications described.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is usually sent in the form of POST request with __AjaxRequestVerificationToken as one of parameters. To successfully send AJAX request you need to:

- Extract this token from the page which uses AJAX (XPath Extractor is the most efficient way to do this)
- Either use sniffer tool or Chrome network logger to capture all of the parameters that are sent with request (make sure you've set "Method" to POST)
- Set "X-Requested-With" header's value to "XMLHttpRequest" and "Content-Type" to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in HTTP Header Manager of your AJAX Post Request sampler
- Set "X-Request-Verification-Token" value to VerificationToken you've extracted